# Correct way to implement a single instance in a module

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am trying to initialize a DB connection in a module and pass to other modules.
My DB connection module (`rdsconnection.js`) is:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
let dbParams = require('./configparams').getDbParams(); 
let schema = (dbParams.db_schema === "" || dbParams.db_schema === undefined) ? "public." : dbParams.db_schema + ".";

// Connect to AWS RDS
let pool;

if(!pool)
{
    console.log("PG pool not initialized. Initializing now.");
    pool = new Pool({
        user: dbParams.username,
        host: dbParams.host,
        database: dbParams.dbname,
        password: dbParams.password,
        port: dbParams.port
    });    
}
else
{
    console.log("PG already initialized.");
}

module.exports = { pool, schema }
```

I want to do to

```
const { pool, schema } = require('../modules/rdsconnection');
```

in multiple modules and want to return only a single `pool` connection object.
I am assuming the `if/else` I am doing is wrong way to go about this.
What is the proper way to initialize an object only once in a module?
Does the code in the module gets run each time another module calls `require()`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you are doing it correctly. the modules wont run multiple times anyways. and even if it did, Your approach makes sure, only one instance is created.

Comment: Thank you @AbhishekAnand. When I called the module multiple times I only got the first `PG pool not initialized.` message. I didn;t get `PG already initialized` so I was assuming something is not right.

Comment: Or you can create class, ES6 code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it. Node.js modules are only loaded once and then [cached](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) for reuse if they are `require`ed multiple times in a program. You can simplify it to this:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');
const dbParams = require('./configparams').getDbParams(); 
const schema = `${dbParams.db_schema || 'public'}.`;

// Connect to AWS RDS
const pool = pool = new Pool({
  user: dbParams.username,
  host: dbParams.host,
  database: dbParams.dbname,
  password: dbParams.password,
  port: dbParams.port
});

module.exports = { pool, schema };
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the `schema` statement too :)

Comment: The documentation you linked mentions `will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.`. Does that mean if I call `require(./rdsconnection)` and then call `require(../modules/rdsconnection)`, it will be executed two times?

Comment: @madu no. If [`require.resolve('./rdsconnection') === require.resolve('../modules/rdsconnection')`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options) then it will get the `module.exports` object from the cache.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. In what cases then would a single module file resolve to different files?